# Can an ASP.NET web application be cloned?

Tags: asp.net, vs-web-application-project

we have a well developed suite of asp.net websites that at a base level handle user authorization, request for access, disclaimer signing, and user management functions.

with a web site, it is easy to copy files, change the connection strings in web.config to point to a new (cloned) database, and start a new website.

can we achieve the same goal if we move to web applications? research so far has not confirmed or refuted this concept.

Comment: _"research so far"_ - try it.

Comment: that's for tomorrow morning. i'm thinking, researching, and asking questions of folks (this list) whom i consider knowledgeable. these are reasonable steps to take.